# VBA Pulling Data with a Schema File

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have this code below

```
Option Explicit

Sub MadMule2()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim el
    Dim els
    Dim colDocLinks As New Collection
    Dim Ticker As String
    Dim lnk
    Dim intCounter as Integer    

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    IE.Visible = False

    Ticker = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    LoadPage IE, "https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?" & _
                  "action=getcompany&CIK=" & Ticker & "&type=10-Q" & _
                  "&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=20"

    Set els = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each el In els
        If Trim(el.innerText) = "Documents" Then
            colDocLinks.Add el.href
        End If
    Next el

    intCounter = 1

     For Each lnk In colDocLinks
        LoadPage IE, CStr(lnk)
        For Each el In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If el.href Like "*[0-9].xml" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(el, "xbrl").Name = "xbrl Map"
            End If
        Next el
    Next lnk
End Sub

Sub LoadPage(IE As InternetExplorer, URL As String)
    IE.navigate URL
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

This comment of [user2140261](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140261/user2140261)

---

*Also why are you using the XML files to get the Schema when your website already has one made for you? Doesn't make sense to let excel guess at making one when there is already one made. AS excel could do it wrong and you might never catch its mistakes.*

---

got me into trying to create an XML Map into Excel by using the data agency's Schema by simply changing this statement:

```
If el.href Like "*.xsd" Then
```

and this statement

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add(el, "Schema").Name = "xbrl Map " & intCounter
```

However when i am trying to do it (by going to XML task pane, pushing Source and then XML Maps) I get this:

[image]

**How is this possible? I open the [Schema file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/10795/000119312514042815/bdx-20131231.xsd) and is see that the root node is one and it is `Schema`**

[image]

While it is reasonable that : *...Doesn't make sense to let excel guess at making one (Excel makes a Schema for you when you import only an XML file) when there is already one made.*

When i imported the [XML file](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/10795/000119312514042815/bdx-20131231.xml) i had one root node made. This was the root node `xbrl` and it made quite easy for me to understand things. Now i get the fragmentation seen in the first picture plus an amazingly long running time.

- Do you believe i should/must refer to different root nodes when i
  want to import different data?
- How could i use the ready-made schema of the data agency which guards
  me against mistake?
- How can i put all of these nodes under one root node (as excel does
  when i import in XML Maps the XML file) instead of having many root
  nodes and at the same time use the Schema?

I hope this edit of the question doesn't turn into a heavy fiasco for me again as the solution for the former 3 edits of this question-thread was rather before my eyes.

Comment: Thanks for the **large**, beautiful screen shots. Please make them ***much smaller***.

Comment: See if you can see them at http://1drv.ms/1hIon0U

Comment: You should look into MSXML it is much faster, secure, and reliable then IE automation.

Comment: Also why are you using the XML files to get the Schema when your website already has one made for you? Doesn't make sense to let excel guess at making one when there is already one made. AS excel could do it wrong and you might never catch its mistakes.

Comment: I really don't know i will try to pull the data by the use of Schema now.

Comment: Mapping XML elements to cells is a built in functionality of Excel and for that reason i thought it would be much faster than anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML-Schema that is referenced on that site is a hell of a beast (considering XML-Schema is prone to beastly constructs). This schema imports several additional schemas (further down, xs:import ...) what might explain the additional schemas available.

On the other hand: Although the automatic XML-Schema generated by Excel is indeed sometimes not complete or fully accurate (types) I would use this schema nevertheless -- if necessary with some corrections (see [Exporting XML from Excel and Keeping Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918347/exporting-xml-from-excel-and-keeping-date-format/8153747#8153747)).

Apart from that I couldn't figure out what you were trying to accomplish, although using MSXML to download the files seems a very reasonable advise.

Sorry for the superficial answer. I hope it helps nonetheless or gives some clues. 
Andreas